# CMake to add arbitrary file to Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to reference extra files (in fact DLL) from my Visual Studio project generated from CMake.

If I add my files from the Visual Studio UI, the XML project file produces something like:

```
<None Include="C:\foo.dll" />
```

Then, this file is properly deployed when debugging my (C++) application on my Windows Phone.

I didn't find anything allowing me to do that directly from CMake.
My attempts so far were to use `source_group` combined with `add_executable` which produces the expected `<None Include="C:\foo.dll" />` but produces a link error (obviously).

Nothing working using `source_files_properties` either.

My final goal is to deploy an executable relying on those DLL but not linking directly against them (so, CMake's `target_link_libraries` doesn't help me), only loading them at runtime using [LoadPackagedLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447159(v=vs.85).aspx).

Has anybody an idea to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FILE(COPY ...)` to copy the DLL into the correct directory in your build tree, if you run directly out of the build tree.  Use `INSTALL()` to install the file along with everything else.

Comment: I already try that but it didn't work since the file isn't referenced by the Visual Project.
I need the same result as the following steps:
`right click on project > add > an existing file > path to my dll`